# Конфигурация сервера на Dual-CPU материнке

Tags: железо, configuration

Была поставлена задача обновить железо местного "сервера" (машина на core i7-2600, 8гб оперативки, 32bit винда с расширенной адресацией). Собственно потребности небольшие - сейчас там сервер терминалов для файловой 1ски (но обсуждается переход на MSSQL-версию, поэтому конфиг больше под это нужно заточить), но 1сник убедил начальство, что при апдейте на новые версии бухгалтерии и пр. железо загнется. Ранее сборками серверов не занимался, нужна помощь. Интересна возможность сборки на материнке с двумя сокетами для последующего доапгрейда при необходимости. В сети 30 компов.

Накидал вот такой конфиг:

- Материнка: SuperMicro X10DRL-i
- CPU Intel Xeon E5-2620 V4
- (RAID1)2xHDD 1 Tb SATA 6Gb / s Seagate Barracuda < ST1000DM010 > 3.5" 7200rpm 64Mb
- БП: Aerocool KCAS PLUS-1000GM 1000W ATX (24+8+2x4+6x6 / 8пин)
- ОЗУ: 2xQUMO < QUM4U-8G2133M15 > DDR4 DIMM 8Gb 2133GHz

Подскажите по конфигу, вытянет ли обычный HDD MSSQL базу (файловая база ща на SSD валяется, без него еле шевелится), или под нее тоже SSD нужен? И будет ли адекватно работать такой конфиг (БП, винты и оперативка довольно дешевые взяты относительно ЦП и материнки)?
Также хотелось бы получить совет по поводу завершения комплектации выше - какой корпус нужен, какие кулеры/радиаторы и сколько.

Comment: Сейчас мне кажется SATA6Gb/s на сервере точно в ущерб будет работать, здесь нужен SAS12GB/s, можно также рассмотреть интерфейс NVMe, скорость винта это основное, упор на несколько сокетов под проц, как по мне - это тупо, сейчас многоядерность прокачана очень внушительно, тем более для ваших нужд, можно также поставить NAS с обычными винтами для бэкапа

Comment: Я подумал что при нашем размере БД (<10GB все базы) и количестве пользователей, нагрузка на винчестер не будет настолько большой.

Comment: Мне кажется, 16G RAM для виндового сервера — это как-то странно. Поставьте хотя бы 128, пусть кэширует вволю.

Comment: 1) 16гб для 1с + терминальная ферма - мало
2) База только на SSD

Comment: Сейчас сервак висит на 8 гигах и ничего, вопрос про MSSQL был